# Maximum Windows volume, laptop's bar is at 50% - how can I boost the system volume further?

Tags: laptop, thinkpad

I have a laptop with Windows 7. I set all the usual volume control are at max (via the mixer), but there is a separate (hardware?) volume bar that is displayed whenever I change the volume, and it is at 50%.

Is there something I'm missing? How can I increase the volume further?

**Edit** - The model is Lenovo Edge, I'm not sure of the exact model, the label on the bottom says "Type: 0217-22G".

**Edit2** - More than fixing the display, what I'm really looking for is a way to arbitrarily boost the volume beyond the max. Why should there be a software imposed max in the first place (well, usability is one reason, but some Youtube videos have really low volume)?

Comment: Hmmm I have a Lenovo ThinkPad T500, and 50 is the MAX volume. You can't set it louder AFAIK.

Comment: @Shiki - this is silly. The speakers are able to physically output more ... why doesn't the OS, or some other software allow you to do this?

Comment: What happens when you disable the HID input service and then try the hardware volume keys?

Comment: @Breakthrough - haven't disabled HID yet (it's my parents' laptop, I don't have access to it ... although this will certainly not help me boost the volume further (see updated question title)

Comment: @DMA57361 - see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97657/should-i-be-allowed-to-offer-external-incentive-bounty-for-questions

Comment: @ripper: are they equally quiet over headphones?

Comment: @sixlettervariables - I don't know, I don't have access to the said laptop right now. Will check it later.

Answer (score 1):

The Lenovo Community Forums have a thread recommending you [uninstall the Realtek driver and use the generic Windows 7 driver](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-Edge/Speaker-volume-uselessly-low-SmartAudio-HD-does-not-work/td-p/412541).

Comment: This seems to be a valid direction ... I'll give that a try.

Comment: Also, per some reviews of various ThinkPad Edge models, "...long battery life time but the volume is not good".

Comment: The battery is sooooo long. It never empties!

Comment: I awarded you the bounty even though I didn't have time to test this yet (it's not my own laptop) - your answers seems closest to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have a laptop that had hardware controls (Like an <kbd>FN</kbd> + key or just volume buttons) that would set the volume on a hardware level as well as the in-Windows mixer controls. Look for any hardware volume controls on your laptop.

Comment: From what I recall, the hardware buttons are equivalent to the OS's ones. Anyway, I believe I tried pressing them and it only got to 50% (I don't have the laptop with me right now, so I can't verify)

Comment: Confirmed. Pressing the volume keys is equivalent to the mixer, and is limited at 50%.

Answer (score 0):

This is worth trying :

1. Right-click on the Volume icon at
   the Task Bar > Playback Devices.
2. Find the device with the green
   check-mark (scroll if required) and
   click it.
3. Click Properties.
4. In the Levels tab, move both sliders
   to 100% and click Apply.
5. Then in the Advanced tab, uncheck
   all under Exclusive mode.
6. Finish with OK.

If this does not work, the free [VLC media player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) can go up to 400% by pressing ctrl-+.

Comment: VLC won't help with Youtube. I'll try what you suggested.

Comment: This [article](http://www.rightnowintech.com/2011/01/fix-low-volume-problem-in-sony-vaio-e.html) might also help.

Comment: And also [this one](http://www.blogsolute.com/play-youtube-videos-vlc-media-player/8816/).

Answer (score 0):

Try using another OSD software. Perhaps the OSD software you use is buggy so it does not show real volume. Compare if the current 50% is equivalent to 100% in new OSD software.

- Mathew Malesek's 3RVX: http://matthew.malensek.net/ / http://matthew.malensek.net/#/Software/
- Microsoft's Intellisync: http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/downloads / http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/d/internet-keyboard

If your ears are so good to fell the difference, play a mp3/wav file in Windows, then use a Live OS running in a CD/DVD or flash drive, like a Linux one (Slax, Ubuntu...), put the volume in maximum level and play the file again. If the volume you heard is "equal", then the 50% displayed in Windows is the maximum.

Edit 1:
Also I know in Windows 7 there is an option to do speakers louder in Control Panel, changing advanced properties of default output, but I am not using W7 at the moment and I did not find how to in internet (later I'll put it here).

Comment: The _real_ issue is that the volume for some vids (e.g. Youtube vids, something that VLC wouldn't help with) is just too low, and I can't artificially boost it.

Comment: I heard that in Linux you can "boost system sound" 50% more (the maximum is 150%). Using VLC you can "boost" in same way a media in it. But for your specific case, I don't know how to solve yet...

Answer (score 0):

It's not a solution to the problem, rather little hack with Windows 7.

Go to

- Control Panel → Hardware and Sound → Sound →
- right-click on your output hardware (I guess in your case it's built-in speakers) → Properties → Enhancements tab (not sure about spelling)
- check "Loundness Equalization" box.

Like I said it's not a solution, but it might help a bit.

One more thing crossed my mind. Did you update you driver? Whose driver do you use?

Answer (score 0):

looks like the Thinkpad volume controls is taking control over the OS volume controls, what follow may help fixing this

1. right click the mixer icon on the
   task bar -> playback
2. select speakers, then properties
3. on the enhancement tab, enable
   **loudness equalization**
4. then, on the 'advanced' tab, uncheck, "**allow application to take exclusive controls over this device**"

back to the main properties windows, go to 'communication' ans select **do nothing**